# How to export SNS topic to be used in different stacks in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

In one Cloudformation template, I create an SNS topic and export it. Note that you cannot export an SNS topic's `Arn` because that attribute is not available to `GetAtt` on [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html).

**BaseStack**

```
Outputs:
  AlarmSNSTopic: 
    Description: Arn for SNS topic related to alarms
    Export:
      Name: AlarmSNSTopic
    Value: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyAlarmSNSTopic", "TopicName"] }
```

Then in a different template, I try to reference that export with something like:

**Functional Stack 1**

```
InputQueueNoMessages:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmDescription: Some Alarm
  ...
  AlarmActions:
    Fn::ImportValue: AlarmSNSTopic
```

When I do, Cloudformation tells me that it expects an ARN, not the topic name.

> ```
> Invalid arn syntax: Blah-AlarmSNSTopic-random
> ```

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm` requires an ARN for `AlarmActions`, but you exported the topic name. The value of your output should be the ARN.

```
Outputs:
  AlarmSNSTopic: 
    Description: Arn for SNS topic related to alarms
    Export:
      Name: AlarmSNSTopic
    Value: !Ref MyAlarmSNSTopic
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do a ref, it would return the topic ARN.

```
Value: !Ref MyAlarmSNSTopic
```

> Ref
>
> For the AWS::SNS::Topic resource, the Ref intrinsic function
>   returns the topic ARN, for example:
>   arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:mystack-mytopic-NZJ5JSMVGFIE.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#w2ab2c21c10d983c11

Comment: You cannot `ref`erence resources created in a different stack without exporting them, unless I'm mistaken? EG https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudformation-update-yaml-cross-stack-references-simplified-substitution/

Comment: you can do a ref at the export instead of getatt